# Updated a table based on a condtion Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, set

I have the following code:

```
-- First Table:  
UPDATE     [H$Agency Header]
SET        [Booking Rating] = '1' --!!!!! CONDTION HERE !!!!!
FROM       [H$Agency Header] AH
INNER JOIN #RatingLines   RL1
ON         RL1.[B_KEY] = AH.[Reservation No_]
WHERE      RL1.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''-- If the Booking have a comment inDB2
AND        [Booking Rating] = '0'    -- Get only Booking without Comments
```

as you can see i set Booking rating to 1 If the inner join found common lines in both tables [H$Agency Header] and #RatingLines. Now I want to say if you didn't find it set it to '0'. Can I put a condition next to the SET command ? how?

Comment: yes you can give case in set command but . can you elaborate your condition?

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you are using. Your title suggests MySQL, but the code suggests SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the above query parses, then you can do what you want with a `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE`.  This requires moving the condition on the comment from the `where` to the `on` clause:

```
UPDATE AH
    SET [Booking Rating] = (CASE WHEN RLI.B_KEY IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END)
    FROM [H$Agency Header] AH LEFT JOIN
         #RatingLines RL1
         ON RL1.[B_KEY] = AH.[Reservation No_] AND
            RL1.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''-- If the Booking have a comment inDB2
    WHERE AH.[Booking Rating] = '0'    -- Get only Booking without Comments
```

NOTE:  If `[Booking Rating]` is an integer, then you should not put `0` and `1` in single quotes.  Although it works, it is misleading to set a numeric column to a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
-- First Table:  
UPDATE     [H$Agency Header]
SET        [Booking Rating] = 
(case when RL1.[B_KEY] is null then '0' -- no match found
else '1'
end )
FROM       [H$Agency Header] AH
left  JOIN RatingLines   RL1 -- change join to Left
ON         RL1.[B_KEY] = AH.[Reservation No_] and  RL1.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''
--WHERE      RL1.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''-- If the Booking have a comment inDB2
--AND        [Booking Rating] = '0'
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df8293/8)</kbd>